# How do I add a mouseover event on a row in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamically populating table and would like to add a mouseover feature

```
(mouseover="style.backgroundColor='#E1EBF4'")
```

to my table row while the data row is being added.

```
function addRecentData(data) {
   $('#newTable tr:last').after('<tr><td class="name"></td><td class="id"></td></tr>');
   var $tr = $('#newTable tr:last');
   $tr.find('.name').html(data.Name);
   $tr.find('.id').html(data.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Note that if you're not concerned about IE6 support, you could use the CSS `:hover` pseudo selector to change the background. This should probably be the first consideration.

```
#newTable ​tr:hover {
    background: #E1EBF4;
}​
```

---

Given your current code, you could just use your `$tr` reference to the table:

```
function addRecentData(data) {
   $('#newTable tr:last').after('<tr><td class="name"></td><td class="id"></td></tr>');
   var $tr = $('#newTable tr:last');
   $tr.find('.name').html(data.Name);
   $tr.find('.id').html(data.Id);
   $tr.mouseover(function() {
       $(this).css('backgroundColor','#E1EBF4');
       // this.style.backgroundColor = '#E1EBF4';  // or you could do this
   });
}
```

Another approach would be to use `inserAfter()` instead of `after()`, and assign the variable immediately.

```
function addRecentData(data) {
   var $tr = $('<tr><td class="name"></td><td class="id"></td></tr>')
                   .insertAfter('#newTable tr:last');
   $tr.find('.name').html(data.Name);
   $tr.find('.id').html(data.Id);
   $tr.mouseover(function() {
       $(this).css('backgroundColor','#E1EBF4');
       // this.style.backgroundColor = '#E1EBF4';  // or you could do this
   });
}
```

Or if each `<tr>` should get the mouseover, you could use `.delegate()` on the `#newTable` to take care of the mouseover.

```
$('#newTable').delegate('tr', 'mouseover', function() {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor','#E1EBF4');
    // this.style.backgroundColor = '#E1EBF4';  // or you could do this
});
```

Now `<tr>` elements will automatically get the functionality you want when they are added to the table.

- http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: $(this).css('backgroundColor','#E1EBF4'); didn't work too well for me.  The other option worked great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should stick to adding your events via jQuery.  You can put the event handler in place **before** adding your rows by using the [*.live()*](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event binding method.  Also, if you want a hover effect, you're better off with *mouseenter* and *mouseleave*, which jQuery provides for browsers that don't already support it:

```
$('#newTable tr').live('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#E1EBF4');
}).live('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', '');
});
```

This is also more efficient than binding to each individual element when it is added dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before you can use .live

```
$('#newTable tr').live('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).css('background','#E1EBF4');
}).live('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).css('background','');
});
```

Be sure you are using mouseenter and mouseleave on the row, not mouseover/mouseout or it will trigger when moving in and out of child elements as well and you will see a flicker of your background changing back and forth.